# array_unshift for multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to insert an array into a multidimensional array as the first element. Example of my original array

```
Array (
    0 => array ( "point1.0" => "some data", "point2.0" => "some data" )
    1 => array ( "point1.1" => "some data", "point2.1" => "some data" )
)
```

Then I have the array that I want to insert as the first Element

```
$newArray = array("point1.2" => "some data", "point2.2" => "some data" )
```

And my result should be

```
Array (
    0 => array ( "point1.2" => "some data", "point2.2" => "some data" )
    1 => array ( "point1.0" => "some data", "point2.0" => "some data" )
    2 => array ( "point1.1" => "some data", "point2.1" => "some data" )
)
```

array_unshift seems to fail in this case. Are there any better solutions than creating a new array and inserting every subarray through a foreach loop?

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't be working. Show your code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`array_unshift`](http://php.net/array_unshift) should work for you.  It should be noted that the function modifies the array passed to it and does not return a new array, so you should **not** be assigning the return value back to the array variable.

Correct:

```
array_unshift($arr, $newArray);
```

Incorrect:

```
$arr = array_unshift($arr, $newArray);
```

Comment: Thank you, I was indeed assigning the return value to a new variable